# Simple IF DAX function (PowerBI)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying this nested IF formula, and it's returning an error.  Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?  I'm creating a new column with this formula for an attendance sheet for an event.

```
IF(AND(new_newattendees[new_attended] = True, new_newattendees[new_register] = True),"Register and Attended",
    IF(AND(new_newattendees[new_attended] = True, new_newattendees[new_register] = False),"Only Attended",
    IF(AND(new_newattendees[new_attended] = False,new_newattendees[new_register] = True),"Only Register",
    IF(AND(new_newattendees[new_attended] = False,new_newattendees[new_register] = False),"NA",0))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it: :)

```
Events Attendance Status = SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    AND(new_newattendees[new_attended] = True,new_newattendees[new_register] = True), "Registered and Attended",
    AND( new_newattendees[new_attended] = True, new_newattendees[new_register] = False),"Attend not register",
    AND(new_newattendees[new_attended] = False, new_newattendees[new_register] = True),"Register not Attend",
    "Missing"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you are seeing error here is because you are trying to use 2 different data types in your IF condition.

1. Text data type for all the satisfied IF condition ("Register and Attended","Only Attended","Only Register","NA") and
2. Whole number Number data type for the last false condition( 0 in IF(AND(new_newattendees[new_attended] = False, new_newattendees[new_register] = False),"NA",0) ).

to fix the issue rewrite the code as :

IF(
AND(new_newattendees[new_attended] = True, new_newattendees[new_register] = True),"Register and Attended",
IF(
AND(new_newattendees[new_attended] = True, new_newattendees[new_register] = False),"Only Attended",
IF(
AND(new_newattendees[new_attended] = False,new_newattendees[new_register] = True),"Only Register",
IF(
AND(new_newattendees[new_attended] = False,new_newattendees[new_register] = False),"NA","0")
)
)
)

Please vote for the answer if it works.

Comment: The error was incorrect syntax, but I'll have to open the file again and check.

Comment: @Unicorn_tech I check the same and it looks correct. Please see the snip below. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtVKm.jpg